# Android loading animation

Tags: java, android

I am searching for some info on how to create loading animation in android. Is it possible to create this animation that i could call this animation in one thread and end in other ?

I seeking for this:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try below Code

ProgressDialog for showing:

```
 ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
                mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mDialog.show();
```

After cancel ProgressDialog below code:

```
 mdialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: In async task i call this and get:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: You must start ProgreeDialog Before Start the thread and dimiss progress Dialog from end thread..!

Comment: In which method i should atar and end ProgressDialog if i am using AsyncTask ?

Comment: Ok.try this tutorial more information http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Answer (score 2):

This is basically done with an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) (Using spinner style) that is started and dismissed by the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads).

Answer (score 2):

You can not start/end ProgressDialog from any thread other that UI thread. In it's simplest for you would want to use AsyncTask methods onPreExecute onPostExecute. But I would be careful with that.

1. you don't want to lose a reference to dialog from async task (user changes orientation or rotates the screen). So you want to keep WeakReference to dialog
2. If you're doing serious loading worj, I'd recomment using Service for it and listening for service callbacks (like broadcasts) to control dialog. This will also allow you separate Activity lifecycle from background work.

Comment: How do you use the Weak Reference? When I use a ProgressDialog in my Async task I get an exception (IllegalArgumentException).