# Android Wear ProgressDialog and MessageAPI problems

Tags: android, wear-os

I currently have an Android Wear app that displays a list of 10 items to the user. When the app is opened there is a splash screen with a single image, while a message is sent to the phone to retrieve the necessary list data.

I want to add a ProgressDialog underneath my image. My first question is, is this possible? If so, how?

I will post the code I have below, but I followed the suggestions on making a ProgressDialog here: [Android loading animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242585/android-loading-animation) . I can successfully create a ProgressDialog, but I'm having some problems.

1. The ProgressDialog view replaces my initial splash screen image.
2. `doInBackground()` calls a function to send a message to the paired phone, for the list data. Since it must wait for a response in `onMessageReceived()`, it immediately calls `onPostExecute()` and closes the dialogue.
3. If I try to manually call `onPostExecute()`, after I have my list data, the ProgressDialog never closes.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
public class InitialActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        MessageApi.MessageListener{
    private WearableListItem[] items = new WearableListItem[10];
    private String nodeID;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;
    private ProgressTask progressTask;
    private boolean done = false;

    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        ProgressDialog asyncDialog = new ProgressDialog(InitialActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            //set message of the dialog
            asyncDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            asyncDialog.setCancelable(false);
            //show dialog
            asyncDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //don't touch dialog here it'll break the application
            //do some lengthy stuff like calling login webservice
            retrieveDeviceNode();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            //hide the dialog
//            if(done)
//            {
                asyncDialog.dismiss();
//            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.load_screen);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
//        retrieveDeviceNode();
        progressTask = new ProgressTask();
        progressTask.execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Wearable.MessageApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, nodeID, message, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        nodeID = messageEvent.getSourceNodeId();
        if (messageEvent.getPath().contains("/joblist")) {
            List<Drawable> drawables = getDrawableList(messageEvent.getData());
            String jobList = messageEvent.getPath().substring(8);
            initJobList(jobList, drawables);
            done = true;
            progressTask.onPostExecute(null);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void retrieveDeviceNode(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();
                if(result.getNodes().size() > 0){
                    nodeID = result.getNodes().get(0).getId();
                    sendMessage("/getWearData");
                }
                else{
                    nodeID = "";
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply add a ProgressBar component to the view that shows the image and show this component when you start the process and hide it when you are done with it?

Comment: That was perfect. I didn't know they are essentially the same thing. Thank you for answering my noob question :)